# Geometric conditions equivalent to a set being the unit circle for some norm

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Here's the question, as in the textbook (Real Mathematical Analysis, Pugh).

> The unit ball with respect to a norm $||\, \cdot \,||$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is
>   $$ \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||\, v \,|| \leq 1 \} . $$
>   a. Find necessary and sufficient geometric conditions on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that it be the unit ball for some norm.
>   b. Find necessary and sufficient geometric conditions that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ be the unit ball for a norm arising from an inner product.

I have proven a. by specifying for a set $V$ the conditions of: convexity of $V$, existence of $\max \{ a \in \mathbb{R} : av \in V \}$ for all non-zero $v \in V$, and $0 \in V$. The 'necessary' direction is rather straightforward, while the 'sufficient' direction can be shown using construction and defining the norm by the reciprocal of the above maximum value.
Note: I haven't done any (general) topology yet, though I've been told that the existence of the maximum of the aforementioned set is equivalent to closedness and boundedness (compactness).

As for (b), my intuition says that the set must be an ellipse (not sure if axis-aligned or generally), but I really don't know where to begin in proving this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: in a. you missed symmetry around the origin

Comment: @WillJagy: Ah, that's right... I used it implicitly in my proof of absolute scalability of the constructed norm, but forgot to mention it. Cheers for pointing it out. (Alas, it doesn't help with b. though!)

Comment: Let the inner product of $(1,0)$ with itself be $a,$ the inner product of $(0,1)$ with itself be $c,$ and the inner product of $(1,0)$ with $(0,1)$ be $b.$ What is the inner product of $(x,y)$ with itself? This is the square of the norm.

Comment: Oh, this is not permitted to become negative, and cannot be $0$ unless both $x,y=0.$

Comment: @WillJagy: I don't quite get your suggestion I'm afraid. What are a, b, and c except arbitrary assignments to variables?

Comment: Arbitrary reals, yes. Trying to get you to write an expression for the (squared) norm of $(x,y)$ in terms of $a,b,c,x,y.$

Comment: @WillJagy: Ah okay. Well in that case, $||(x, y)||^2 = \langle (x, y), (x, y) \rangle = x^2 a^2 + 2xyb + y^2 c^2$, no?

Comment: well, no. What happened to the $c?$

Comment: Have you had any linear algebra at all?

Comment: @WillJagy: Typo.

Comment: I've done a good deal of linear algebra. Is that not even close?

Comment: It's just expanding the inner product using its laws...

Comment: Try $(x,y) = x \cdot (1,0) + y \cdot (0,1)$ and be really really really really really  careful.

Comment: Yeah that's precisely what I did, hmm... let me double check.

Comment: Try again, maybe this is the problem: call (1,0) with itself $a,$ then (0,1) with itself $c,$ finally (1,0) with (0,1) $b.$

Comment: @WillJagy: Okay, I see the problem. I made a bit of a muddled analogy with the expansion of the square of a binomial... (never had the patience for rote calculation, even when not doing it leads me astray). So I believe it's correct if you replace $a^2$ with $a$ and $c^2$ with $c$ above?

Comment: Probably, please type it properly

Comment: Hah okay, you're a stickler, but I'm happy to oblige if it progresses us... Is $||(x, y)||^2 = \langle (x, y), (x, y) \rangle = x^2 a + 2xyb + y^2 c$ any better? :)

Comment: I suppose this should remind me of the equation of an ellipse now?

Comment: good. Most people write $a x^2 + 2 b x y + c y^2. $

Comment: Okay fair enough. I guess that's just how I expected it, but indeed, that convention sounds right.

Comment: Meanwhile, $a x^2 + 2 b x y + c y^2 = 1$ is a conic section, with some restrictions on $a,b,c$ (inequalities only) it describes an ellipse.

Comment: Looking at the implicit Cartesian equation for an ellipse, it would now seem I need the condition $b^2 < ac$. Tell me if I'm jumping the gun though.

Comment: Ah yes, very good. Been a while since I did all the conics stuff, but that strongly rings a bell for me.

Comment: yes, as long as $a,c$ are positive.

Comment: Yeah. And this is indeed the case, because of the positivity law of the inner product, as you hinted at earlier...

Comment: @WillJagy: Are there any other insights now, or is all that remains filling in the details of the proof?

Comment: that should do it

Comment: @WillJagy: Many thanks!

Comment: I know this question is almost 10 years old, but maybe you should write an answer to your own question summarising what the conditions you got for part a and b are.